# 3D volume integral and changing sign

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, calculus, propagator

Let $k$ be 3d momentum. What happens with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{3}k$ when I change $k$ to $-k$? I thought that 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{3}k&=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d(-k_{x})d(-k_{y})d(-k_{z})\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk_{x}dk_{y}dk_{z}\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{3}k
\end{align}

But in the Schwartz's book "quantum field theory" it says that 3d volume is an invariant under such transformation. But why?

[image]

The question appears when one calculate a Feynman propagator.

Comment: What about integration limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d(-k_{x})d(-k_{y})d(-k_{z})$

You forgot to change the extremes of integration, they give you a $(-)^3$ that compensate for the $-$ you addressed in the substitution

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\rr}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\d}{\, d^nx}$I will give a more mathematical answer. Observe that for a diffeomorphism (read: coordinate change) $\phi: V \to U$ for open subsets $U,V \subset \rr^n$ and an integrable function $f: U \to \rr $ we have the transformation rule:

$$\int_{U} f \d = \int_V (f \circ \phi) \left|\det{J_\phi}\right|\d $$

where $\det J_\phi$ is the determinant of the Jacobi-Matrix of $\phi$. Observe the absolute value sign, which everybody forgets about. In our case we have $V=U=\rr^3$ and $\phi(x) = -x$, hence $J_\phi = -\mathrm{Id}$ and thus $|\det J_\phi| = |-1| =1$ Thus we get:

$$\int_{\rr^3} f(x)\, d^3x = \int_{\rr^3} f(-x) \, d^3x$$

Note that the crucial difference between the substitution rule

$$ \int_a^b f(x) \,dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(g(x)) \,g'(x)\, dx$$

and the transformation rule in 1d:

$$ \int_{[a,b]} f(x) \,dx = \int_{g([a,b])} f(g(x)) \,|g'(x)|\, dx$$

where the former uses the order (i.e. you can write stuff like $x>y$) of $\rr$ to write an expression of the form $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$, whereas the latter does not.